# Yanking all marked lines in vim

Tags: vim

Often times when reviewing log files in vim, I'll highlight interesting lines using marks. At some point, I'd like to be able to copy all of the interesting lines (either all marked lines, or a list of marks) to either a register or another file (it doesn't really matter which; the goal is to facilitate writing a summary). I haven't been able to find any built in way to do this; is it possible in vim?

I suppose it's probably a fairly straightforward function; probably looking something like this, but my vimscript abilities are very weak:

```
for cur_mark in list_of_marks
    goto mark
    yank current line and append to register
```

Has anyone ever written anything similar that they can point me to?

Thanks

EDIT: I posted the accepted solution at https://github.com/mikeage/vim-yankmarks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mikeage had a great idea; here's a more refined version of his function turned into a command:

```
":YankMarks [{marks}] [{register}]
"                   Yank all marked (with [a-z] / {marks} marks) lines into
"                   the default register / {register} (in the order of the
"                   marks).
function! s:YankMarks( ... )
    let l:marks = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    let l:register = '"'
    if a:0 > 2
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echomsg 'Too many arguments'
        echohl None
        return
    elseif a:0 == 2
        let l:marks = a:1
        let l:register = a:2
    elseif a:0 == 1
        if len(a:1) == 1
            let l:register = a:1
        else
            let l:marks = a:1
        endif
    endif

    let l:lines = ''
    let l:yankedMarks = ''
    for l:mark in split(l:marks, '\zs')
        let l:lnum = line("'" . l:mark)
        if l:lnum > 0
            let l:yankedMarks .= l:mark
            let l:lines .= getline(l:lnum) . "\n"
        endif
    endfor

    call setreg(l:register, l:lines, 'V')

    echomsg printf('Yanked %d line%s from mark%s %s',
    \   len(l:yankedMarks),
    \   len(l:yankedMarks) == 1 ? '' : 's',
    \   len(l:yankedMarks) == 1 ? '' : 's',
    \   l:yankedMarks
    \) . (l:register ==# '"' ? '' : ' into register ' . l:register)
endfunction
command! -bar -nargs=* YankMarks call <SID>YankMarks(<f-args>)
```

Comment: Excellent! Now I have to convince people to downvote my answer and give the credit to you :)

Comment: @Mikeage Oh no, the main credit still goes to you, as I merely provide a somewhat better implementation. I'd suggest that people upvote both :-)

Answer (score 7):

As always, there are few things that are more motivating than asking for help. Here's what I came up with; feedback welcome.

```
function! Yankmark()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let n = 0
    " I should really make this a parameter...
    let marks_to_yank="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    let nummarks = strlen(marks_to_yank)
    " Clear the a register
    let @a=''
    while n < nummarks
        let c = strpart(marks_to_yank, n, 1)
        " Is the mark defined
        if  getpos("'".c)[2] != 0
            " using g' instead of ' doesn't mess with the jumplist
            exec "normal g'".c
            normal "Ayy
        endif
        let n = n + 1
    endwhile
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4):

A different way of accomplishing this might be using the `:global` command. The global command takes the form `:g/{pattern}/{cmd}`. The command, `{cmd}`, will be executed on all lines matching `{pattern}`.

Append lines matching a pattern to a register:

```
:g/pattern/yank A
```

Append matching line to a log file:

```
:g/pattern/w >> file.log
```

Of course if you want to find line matching a mark you can match it in your pattern. The following pattern matches a line with mark `m`.

```
:g/\%'m/w >> file.log
```

To do something like this. (Note: I am using `\v` to turn on very magic)

```
:g/\v(%'a|%'b|%'m)/yank A
```

Of course if a pattern won't work you can do this by hand. Instead of marking the lines just build up the lines as you go. Just yank a line to an uppercase register to append.

```
"Ayy
```

Or do a write append with a range of a single line

```
:.w >> file.log
```

For more help see

```
:h :g
:h :w_a
:h /\%'m
:h /\v
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
:redir @a
:silent marks XYZN
:redir END
"ap
```

That way the output of the `:marks` command will be redirected to the `a` register. Note, that it will only lists (in the above case) the `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `N` marks (as the arguments), and if there was an `a` register, it will be deleted/overwritten.

Also note, that it might not give the desired output, but gives you a starting point...

Comment: Great idea! There's a bit of extra "metadata" this way, of course, but that might actually be helpful in many cases. And it's definitely simpler than what I did

Answer (score 3):

I like the solution from Mikeage, though I would probably solve this with the [multiselect - Create multiple selections and operate](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=953) plugin. This also has the benefit that you don't run out of marks.

With the plugin, you can select lines with `<Leader>msa` or `:MSAdd`. Finally, yank all lines with:

```
:let @a=''
:MSExecCmd yank A
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use an **upper-case** register name when yanking into a specific register, Vim will append the yanked content instead of overwriting the register's value.

So, for example:

- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> - yank current line to register `a`, overwriting
- [move]
- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>**A**</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> - append this line to register `a`
- [move]
- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - paste all yanked material

See `:help quotea` for more details.

Comment: that's what I did in my solution above

Comment: @Mikeage My point is that you don't need a function. You can just accumulate the text into a register by hand as you go.

Comment: Ah, true. But the whole Q was how to automate the process.